# Writting a method to check the number of vowels in a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a hash of data that is holding different strings as its Key. I need to create a new method in my class that will count the number of vowels in each key and then return the key with the most vowels. I am very stuck and this is what I have so far.

```
def favorite_wish
  vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]
  @submitted_wishes.each_key do |wish|
    wish.split(' ')
    wish.each do |check|
      if check == vowels
    end
  end
end
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

[`String#count`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-count) might help you:

```
# this will return the key with the max number of vowels
def favorite_wish
  @submitted_wishes.keys.max_by { |wish| wish.count('aeiou') }
end

# this will return the value to the key with the max number of vowels
def favorite_wish
  max_key = @submitted_wishes.keys.max_by { |wish| wish.count('aeiou') }
  @submitted_wishes[max_key]
end
```

Comment: I believe the key is to be returned.

Answer (score 0):

This will get the key with the most vowels:

```
@submitted_wishes.keys.max_by { |key| key.count('aeiou') }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following methods:

```
def count_vowels(str)
  str.count 'aeiou'
end

def highest_value_key(hash)
  hash.key(hash.values.max)
end
```

The idea behind these methods is to separate concerns and make it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

```
h = { "Mary"=>"Mary", "quite"=>"contrary", "how"=>"does your", "garden"=>"grow?" }

h.map { |k,_| [k.count('aeiou'), k] }.max.last
  #=> => "quite"
```

The steps:

```
a = h.map { |k,_| [k.count('aeiou'), k] }
  #=> [[1, "Mary"], [3, "quite"], [1, "how"], [2, "garden"]] 
b = a.max
  #=> [3, "quite"]
b.last
  #=> "quite"
```

See [Array#<=>](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D) for an explanation of how arrays are ordered (when computing `max`).

If keys `k1` and `k2` tie for the maximum number of vowels, `k1 <=> k2` breaks the tie (`k1` is returned if `k1 <=> k2 #=> -1`, `k2` is returned if `k1 <=> k2 #=> 1`, either key might be returned if `k1 <=> k2 #=> 0`. See [String#<=>](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E).